# How to create a Custom jQuery like this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

## What I want

I want to create a function logs a string in my console. Below is just an example to show what I want.

```
var helloWorld = 'Hello World';
helloWorld.log();

function log(string)
{
   console.log(string);
}
```

The `helloWorld.log();` part isn't working like expected but I want this to be done but I don't know how.

## What I have tried

[Looking at this example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-jqplugin/index.html)

### 1

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.log= function() {
    console.log($(this));
  };
})(jQuery);
```

### 2

```
var log = function() {
    console.log($(this));
}
```

### 3

```
jQuery.fn.log = function(){
    console.log($(this));
}
```

## Error that drives me mad

> TypeError: helloWorld.log is not a function

Comment: You need to manipulate the `String.prototype`. No jQuery needed.

Comment: Your Link doesn't work, 404 Not Found

Comment: Why on earth don't you stick with `console.log`itself, which you'll end using anyway? :))

Comment: @moonwave99 Because I don't want to type `console.log(string);` all the time. Also this is to create learn custom jquery plugins

Comment: I hope you know what you are doing.. that code looks pretty much like a bad idea ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to print it on the hello world variable (which is a String) you can use a prototype function to provide a log method to Strings.

E.g. Something like this:

```
String.prototype.log= function() {
    console.log(this.toString());
});
```

Then when you call `helloWorld.log()` it should call this function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked! Needed to add `this.toString()`

Answer (score 3):

To be able to do `"Hello World".log()` you would have to extend the native String object, e.g.:

```
String.prototype.log = function() { console.log(this); }
```

to use `log` instead of `console.log`, you need something like this:

```
window.log = (window.console && window.console.log && window.console.log.bind) ?
    console.log.bind(console) : 
    function (e) {alert(JSON.stringify(e)); };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked! Needed to add `this.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Change the `helloWorld.log();` to `log(helloWorld);`.

this may help